# Phonegap iOS app screen slides up on double tap

Tags: iphone, ios, html, cordova

I am developing a phonegap app for iOS. The main screen slides up when i double tap at the bottom of the screen. This only happens in the Portrait mode.

I have tried disabling the scroll.. but that hasn't worked. This is my html code :

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0 " />
<body>
<div class="mainScreenContent" align="center">
<table>
<form>
<tbody>
<tr >
<td>
<button type="submit" class="largeButton grayGradientEffect">Button 1</button>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td >
<button type="submit" class="largeButton grayGradientEffect" onclick="">Button 2</button>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</form>
</table>
</div>
</body>
```

Here are Screen Shots:

This is what the main screen looks like:

[image]

This is what it looks like after double tapping on the bottom:

[image]

Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using jquery, intercept this event.

Solution by Johan Sundström below

https://gist.github.com/2047491

To use, add the above to your javascript. Then intercept on whichever element is appropriate.

e.g.

```
$("body").nodoubletapzoom();
```

Comment: This worked great. I had to called it on a DIV instead of body to prevent some CSS irregularities.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding the following to your meta viewport query?

```
user-scalable=0
```