# How to prevent mobile scrolling on double tap in PhoneGap?

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, webview

I'm using AppGyver's SteroidsJS (essentially PhoneGap with enhanced performance and Native UI) to create a web app.  I noticed that when I double tap on an element, it will scroll to that element, even if I have disabled WebView overscroll.  This is a problem, because if the WebView content is shorter than the screen size, I can't even scroll back up.  Is there a fix for this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

There has been some discussion of PhoneGap's tap delay and double-tap problem. For example, check this StackOverflow thread: [Phonegap iOS app screen slides up on double tap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12673951/phonegap-ios-app-screen-slides-up-on-double-tap)

I have been trying to figure this out as well, and here are some approaches that I have tried:

1. **IOS** This is specifically for IOS. Try modifying your /config.xml file to  change "DisallowOverscroll" to true.

   ```
   <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
   ```
2. **HTML solution:** This could be a solution to a single page web-app. Check your app's viewport meta tag. Common convention is to infer the viewport width and height from device, for example

   ```
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height">
   ```

   I have found that this allows some additional space in the browser area. Hard-coding the screen size of device solved this problem for me. For example,

   ```
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=1024, height=768">
   ```

   Add same dimensions to any canvas element on the html page.

   ```
   <canvas width=1024, height=768" ...>
   ```

   This approach seems to be working, at least on my iPad.
3. **Javascript/JQuery:** The StackOverflow link above talks specifically about the jQuery approach. That means effectively interpret the double-tap event using this gist: https://gist.github.com/johan/2047491 and then call the event handler appropriately from your webapp, e.g.

   ```
   $("body").nodoubletapzoom();
   ```

   I haven't had much of a success with this.